# Linq to get values from 2 list with one unique Id

Tags: c#, linq

I have one class to bind for ex.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, this class will get values from different tables but they have common ID.

here is the Lists that I am getting in my loop.

```
var List1 = item.TicketTypes.Where(m => m.PerformanceID == item.Id)
                    .Select(t => new { t.Name, t.ID});

var List2 = item.Pricies.Where(m => m.PerformanceID == item.Id)
                    .Select(t => new { t.Price, t.ID });
```

> item is object of for each loop instance.

What I want is,

**I want List of MyClass filled with Entity Name and Price as per their ID.**

Comment: can you describe with some data ?

Comment: have you tried anything? Like `join`?.. and what is `item`? Currently it is asking for someone to write the code for you - please show what you tried

Comment: @GiladGreen item is instance in my loop, I tried linq Join, but as I am following .net boilerplate Repository architecture, it's not easy to bind all services in join, so i am trying this way..

Comment: have you tried something like this?
```.Select(t => new MyClass() { Price =t.Price, Id =t.ID,Name =t.Name });```

Comment: @FrankM, I am getting price in list2 while name is in List1, how you will join this?

Comment: there is a linq method join

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much informations here for me to test this, but I have this to suggest:

```
// Make sure to add a constructor to MyClass
var List1 = item.TicketTypes.Where(m => m.PerformanceID == item.Id)
                            .Select(t => new MyClass(t.Name, t.ID, item.Pricies.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PerformanceID == t.ID).Price));
```

This should give you the desired result, but like I said I don't have enough informations to test this so make sure you comment the problems so we can fix them together.

Answer (score 1):

In a Linq Statement, if my assumptions are right(cannot test it):

```
var result= from t1 in item.TicketTypes
            join t2 in item.Pricies on t1.ID equals t2.ID
            select new MyClass() { Id = t1.ID, Name = t1.Name, Price = t2.Price };
```

use `.ToList()` if you need a List

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var query = List1.Join(List2, l1 => l1.Id, l2 => l2.Id, (l1, l2) => new { ID = l1.Id, Name = l1.Name, Price = l2.Price });


foreach (var obj in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", obj.ID, obj.Name, obj.Price);
}
```